# dozer with maven

Tags: maven, dozer

I wanted to download the latest release of Dozer mapper from github, but I didn't find any jar.

There is pom.xml file and I try to compile with command `mvn package`. I also added every dependencies to pom.xml file. It created `dozer-5.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

Next I imported this jar to my project, but it throws me `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory`.

I also tried to create POM project in the netbeans and build with dependencies. After import to my project, it throws me the same exception.

I don't have any experiences with maven. How can I get correct JAR file?

Answer (score 1):

Guess your `dozer-package` has a dependency to `slf4j`, right?

Then you should checkout this Maven-Plugin: [Maven-Assembly-Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)

This will put your required dependencies into the jar.

[Here you can read, how to use it](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html)

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
        <mainClass>your.main.class</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
       <phase>package</phase>
         <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

If you want always execute the assemby-plugin when you invoke `mvn clean package`
add this to your maven-assembly-plugin:

```
 <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
 </executions>
```

Comment: yes, it has got dependencies to commons-beanutils, org.apache.commons, org.slf4j. Can you tell me how can I retrieve properly value for mainClass?

Comment: This is your Main-class with the qualified-name. I linked the site, where you can read, how to use it. Also did an update of my answer.

Comment: in pom.xml file is this plugin included, but without configuration and executions. Here is link https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: I can't package it, too (missing dependencies). But the version 5.3.2 (not really old) is available here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/dozer/files/dozer/1.0/

Answer (score 0):

You have a correct jar. Simple add commons-beanutils lang and slf4j to you project with dozer or add this libraries as a maven dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Jars required for **Dozer** dependency.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Make the entry in pom.xml file.Make sure the required Jars are present.

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
        <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
      <properties>
<osgi.version>4.3.0</osgi.version>
```

Comment: He has already added the jar. It's the dependencies that's missing. Especially the commons jar where the exception occurs