# Maven Junit test case crashing with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

Tags: java, maven, junit, dozer

I have been trying to implement a Junit test case for a service which returns what are the different type of resources as shown in the **Tester code** below:

```
public class Tester {

    MyInfoService myInfoService=null;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception{
        myInfoService = new MyInfoService();
        System.out.println(" @#$#@ myInfoService ="+myInfoService.getAllMyResourceTypes().size());
    }

    @Test
    public void testResTypeAll() {
        List<MyTypeInfoBean> resTypeBeanList = myInfoService.getAllMyResourceTypes();
        assertEquals("Testing size for res type...", 18, resTypeBeanList.size());
    }
}
```

**Service class where the error occurs:**

```
public class MyInfoService implements MyInfoServiceRemote {

           // some code here

            @Override
            public List<MyTypeInfoBean> getAllMyResourceTypes() {
            List<MyResourceTypeInfoDTO> resourceList = new ArrayList<>();
            List<MyTypeInfoBean> resourceListBean = new ArrayList<>();
            MyResourceTypeInfoDTO myResTypeInfoDTO = null;
            try {
            HashMap<Integer,MyConstantsUtilClass.MyResourceTypes> restypemap =      (HashMap<Integer,   MyResourceTypes>)MyConstantsUtilClass.MyResourceTypes.getRestypemap();
            Set<Map.Entry<Integer, MyConstantsUtilClass.MyResourceTypes>>   restypemapEntrySet = restypemap.entrySet();
            for (Entry<Integer, MyResourceTypes> entry : restypemapEntrySet) {
                myResTypeInfoDTO = new MyResourceTypeInfoDTO();
                // code to read the entry values and populate my DTO
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            // size gets printed, so everything is fine till now
            System.out.println("@#$#@ resourceList ="+resourceList.size());
        // The resource list is printed correctly above.The problem begins below
                Mapper mapper=null;
                if (resourceList != null) {
                    System.out.println("resourceList is not null object");
                    System.out.print("Original contents of al: ");
                    try {
                // this does not work and get a NoClassDefError
                mapper= DozerBeanMapperSingletonWrapper.getInstance();          } catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Iterator<MyResourceTypeInfoDTO> itr = resourceList.iterator();
                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    MyResourceTypeInfoDTO element = (MyResourceTypeInfoDTO)                     itr.next();
                    if (mapper == null)
                    System.out.println("Mapper is  NULL");
                    MyTypeInfoBean beanElement = mapper.map(element, MyTypeInfoBean.class);
                    resourceListBean.add(beanElement);
                    }
            return resourceListBean;
            }
    // other methods here
    }
```

**Below is the error log I get on running the Junit test case:**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.<clinit>(DozerBeanMapper.java:58)
    at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapperSingletonWrapper.getInstance(DozerBeanMapperSingletonWrapper.java:43)
at com.inv.service.MyInfoService.getAllResourceTypes(MyInfoService.java:508)
at com.bel.tropo.tester.Tester.setUp(Tester.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

**My pom.xml file has the dozer dependency correctly mentioned as :**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
            <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>*</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

The dependencies required by dozer are already resolved through mvn dependency:resolve.

Should I downgrade to a lower version of dozer and check if it works?

These two ([How can I resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23985986/how-can-i-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-slf4j-loggerfactory) and [dozer with maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010927/dozer-with-maven/36398136#36398136)) questions don't seem to give me a solution or am I missing something?
Any help would be great.

Comment: Why are you excluding all transitive dependencies?

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke Do i need to explicitly mention them in my pom.xml file? I guess not as long as those are available in my local or central repo.?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. You don't need to explicitly include them, but what you're doing *right now* is explicitly *excluding* them

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke sorry still didn't get it. How am I doing that ?

Comment: The dependencies need to be at the classpath of your Java VM. Having them just at your disk is not enough. Excluding all transitive dependencies of dozer makes no sense for me. You could exclude or manage certain dependencies in case of a conflict. The command "mvn dependency:tree" displays all dependencies of your module. It can help you to analyze your module.

Comment: @dirai like this: `<exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>*</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>`

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke let me fix this! Thanks

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke  I tried that but it didn't work. I m home from Office. Let me try the solution glytching has mentioned. It's definitely with some of the version mismatch problem. However it's nice to know about <exclusions> on which I hadn't bothered much. I'll go through the maven doc again to understand it's repercussions.

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html Thank you Jeroen! I was too lazy to check it at first place.

Answer (score 1):

Restate your dozer dependency as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
    <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The [dozer-5.3.2-pom](http://central.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/dozer/dozer/5.3.2/dozer-5.3.2.pom) declares SLF4J as a transitive dependency so it will be provided for you as soon as you remove the unwanted exclusions from your Dozer declaration.

Comment: I have removed the exclusions tag. It was a mistake to copy it unknowingly. But the problem remains with a different log. I now get a NoClassDef FoundError for StaticLoggerBinder. I guess I might have to downgrade my dozer version to 2.2 for this to work.

Comment: <dependency> <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId> <artifactId>dozer</artifactId> <version>5.5.1</version> </dependency> solved it for me besides getting rid of exclusions.

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
<groupId>
net.sf.dozer
</groupId> 
<artifactId>
dozer
</artifactId>
<version>
5.5.1
</version>
</dependency>
```

Updating the dozer version and doing a maven compile/install solved it for me besides getting rid of exclusions.